# Top n conditional formatting - with a tie breaker

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, countif

For each row in an Excel sheet I need to highlight the top six values. I tried using conditional formatting for Top 6 but I faced the following issue, for a row such as:

> 189    0   500 900 0   210 0   500 0   500 0   0   1060    883 883

the top six values are 1060, 900, 883, 883, 500 and 500. As you can see, there are two `500`s in my top six but three `500`s in the entire row. Conditional Formatting selects all values that are equal to values in Top 6, so it will highlight seven cells.

Is there a way to work around this, without adding any technical cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ties may be broken with a COUNTIF adjustment. For example a CF rule formula of the kind:

```
=RANK(A1,$A$1:$O$1,0)+COUNTIF($A$1:A$1,A1)-1<7
```

`<7` for the six you specified, though it depends upon when ranking ascending or descending. Ties are broken "in order" - the first found is accepted (count of 1 less 1 means no adjustment), others of the same value are down/up graded accordingly.

---

**To apply this Conditional Formatting rule formula:**

Select the range to which it is to apply (in this case taken as A1:O1).
Click on down arrow in HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting.
Click on New Rule...
Click on *Use a formula to determine which cells to format*.
Under *Format values where this formula is true:* enter:

```
 =RANK(A1,$A$1:$O$1,0)+COUNTIF($A$1:A$1,A1)-1<7
```

Click on <kbd>Format...</kbd>.
Select choice of formatting.
Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.
Click <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Comment: Unfortunately this returns 1 for 1060, 2 for 900, 4 for both 883, 7 for all 3 500, so in fact it now rejects all 500s. I was actually wondering if I could use something like column(A1)*0.0000001+A1 for the rank, but I also need to add this in the range, and this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work and I removed the <7. If I keep the <7 it returs indeed TRUE or FALSE but still FALSE for all the 500s

Comment: Thanks. I missed a $ the first time around. I need a dollar :)